# mysql dump fails when done by root user

Tags: mysql

In Ubuntu server 16.04 xenial in a LEMP stack I executed `mysql -u root  -p` (then root's password), and then, when inside the mysql shell:

```
mysqldump --databases "${domain}" > test.sql
```

but for some reason this fails:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump --databases MY_DB_NAME > dump.sql'
>   at line 1

Why this simple mysqldump command fails?

### Update:

Executing the same command outside the Mysql CLI, fails as well:

```
mysqldump --databases "${domain}" > test.sql
```

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only gave the name without user and password credentials.

This works:

```
mysqldump -u root -p"${rpsw}" "${domain}" > test.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` is a program.  It is not a SQL statement.  You don't run it at a `mysql>` prompt -- you run it from a system shell prompt.

Comment: Outside execution fails as well, please see update.